# multiple iframes not loading in DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, iframe

Hi there I have the following iframes:

```
<div id="dialog" title="Audit Log" style="display: none; " >
    <p>
        <iframe src="" id="IframeAuditLog" width="1000" height="250" />
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p> 
        <iframe src="DocumentManagerForm.htm" id="DocumentManagerFrame" width="0" height="0" />
    </p>
</div>
```

I have tried both ...

```
$(window).load(function (eventObject) {

});
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function (eventObject) {

});
```

but inside either one of these functions I can only access the first Iframe in this case IframeAuditLog in the DOM. If I change the HTML to be the following:

```
<div>
<p> 
    <iframe src="DocumentManagerForm.htm" id="DocumentManagerFrame" width="0" height="0" />
</p>
</div>
<div id="dialog" title="Audit Log" style="display: none; " >
<p>
    <iframe src="" id="IframeAuditLog" width="1000" height="250" />
</p>
```

... Only DocumentManagerFrame is loaded in the DOM ... Any one have any idea whats going on?

Comment: What do you mean "I can only access the first iframe"? What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: It's because iFrame elements aren't **self closing**, add a closing `</iframe>` tag as well.

Comment: @Barmar the iframe is not listed in the DOM if I do a document.geElementById I can only retrieve the first Iframe if I try referencing the second one I get a null

Comment: Also, you should realize that `$(document).ready()` on your own document will not tell you when the iframes are loaded.  They have their own load timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to actually close the iframe, otherwise it stays open until the browser decides to fix it and add the closing tag, and when that is, is anyones guess ?

```
<iframe src="" id="IframeAuditLog" width="1000" height="250"></iframe>
```